# Date in mysql database issue

Tags: mysql, date

So I'm simply trying to grab a date from the database from the query. Then simply move the date to a different column.

```
$bo_date_grabber = tep_db_query("SELECT backorder_date 
                                 FROM pos_products 
                                 WHERE orders_id = '" . $oID . "' 
                                 AND products_model = '" . $fixer . "' ");

while($date_grabber = tep_db_fetch_array($bo_date_grabber))
{
    tep_db_query("UPDATE pos_products 
                  SET bo_days = 'NULL', 
                      bo_checker = '$seven', 
                      in_stock = '$zero', 
                      backorder_date ='$date_grabber[backorder_date]' 
                  WHERE 
                      orders_id= '$oID' AND products_model= '$fixer' ");
}
```

I thought this was going to be quick and simply. Unfortunately I'm running into a problem where the date does not update correctly. The date is converted to a default 0000-00-00. Which is not what I want. Any ideas?

Comment: 0000-00-00 is the default date value for empty set.  Is the backorder_date field is actually populated?  NULL value being set directly inline like you have it is going to put it in as a empty set... What happens if you add to the where clause of the original query `and backorder_date is not null` or you may need to evaluate the bo_date_grabber date for null and adjust the query to handle the NULL value. A paramaterized query wouldn't have this problem however.

Comment: echo your mysql update script and execute it in pma for example - look at error - fix mysql script =\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you have an empty string or the date format is wrong. Remember the date format in Mysql is yyyy-mm-dd.

Comment: It was pulling an empty string the whole time. Thank you.